# Здравствуйте, мне нужно вывести количество оставшегося заряда батареи на смартфоне с помощью шкалы

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, ar

```
public static float GetBatteryLevel()
{


    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
    {
        try
        {
            using (AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
            {
                if (null != unityPlayer)
                {
                    using (AndroidJavaObject currActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
                    {
                        if (null != currActivity)
                        {
                            using (AndroidJavaObject intentFilter = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.IntentFilter", new object[]{ "android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" }))
                            {
                                using (AndroidJavaObject batteryIntent = currActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("registerReceiver", new object[]{null,intentFilter}))
                                {
                                    int level = batteryIntent.Call<int>("getIntExtra", new object[]{"level",-1});
                                    int scale = batteryIntent.Call<int>("getIntExtra", new object[]{"scale",-1});

                                    // Error checking that probably isn't needed but I added just in case.
                                    if (level == -1 || scale == -1)
                                    {
                                        return 50f;
                                    }
                                    return ((float)level / (float)scale) * 100.0f;

                                   
                                }
                           
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
         
        }
    }
 
    return 100;

}
```

это можно сделать с помощью этого кода? помогите пожалуйста, я столько методов перепробовал, и уже не знаю что делать...

Comment: Есть специальный метод (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-batteryLevel.html) для определения заряда, не понимаю зачем вам тот код, который вы выкладываете. Уточните что вы имеете в виду под шкалой. Самую простую можно будет сделать буквально из 2-ух картинок - рамки и содержимого, которое будет растягиваться через Transform.localScale и менять цвет в зависимости от значения заряда.

Comment: Да через компонент слайдер это делается. Даж скейл прям менять не нужно https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCAo-uyb94c

Comment: Можно ещё ступенчатую через какой-нибудь из Layout Group сделать, добавлять ячейки на каждые 25%

Comment: Во-первых, вам не кажется, что если вам в коде последовательно приходится открывать **ДЕВЯТЬ** отступов подряд, то вы делаете что-то не так? ВО-вторых, блок catch не должен быть пустым. В-третьих, ваш вопрос не понятен. [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), см. фразу `Сначала более подробно опишите проблему, которую вы сформулировали в заголовке.`. Что вы подразумеваете под шкалой (вам в комментариях пытаются предложить разные варианты, а так быть не должно: вопрос должен быть точен и однозначен),

Answer (score 1):

Я не понял ваш код, к тому же ваш вопрос не точен. Поэтому просто опишу, как сделать разные шкалы для отражения количества заряда.

---

Количество заряда на устройстве можно определить с помощью метода [SystemInfo.batteryLevel](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-batteryLevel.html), который возвращает значение от 0 до 1, соответствующее нынешнему заряду. Возвращаем -1, если на данном устройстве невозможно определить уровень заряда.

---

Шкалу можно создать разными способами:

- Самый простой - шкала-слайдер. Ее значение можно установить через `GetComponent<Slider>().value`. Для создания самого слайдера нужно удалить из него все, кроме заднего фона и цветного заполнителя (который по-моему называется fill). Также нужно пометить interectable на false в инскпеторе.
- Интересен также вариант SmorclRL о создании ступенчатой шкалы. Для этого одному объекту добавляем LayoutGroup, в него помещаем полоски (обычно разной высоты) 4 или 5... Настраиваем параметры отступов в LayourGroup. В коде делаешь метод

```
public Transform Lines[];
void setValue (float value) {
    float percent = value / maxValue * 100;
    int linesVisible = percent / percentPerLine; // percentPerLine = 100/количество полосок
    for (int i = 0; i < linesVisible; i++) 
        Lines[i].setActive(true);
    for (int i = linesVisible; i < Lines.Length; i++)
        Lines[i].setActive(false);
}
```

Comment: Если вам помог мой ответ, пожалуйста, примите его, нажав на галочку.